Prevent Google Translate from changing links
I have an online newsletter in Dutch. For any international readers, I provide a link to translate the page into English via Google Translate (https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&u=someURL...). This works great. Sometimes a small text should not be translated but kept literally, then I can use <span class="notranslate">Nederlands</span>.
Unfortunately however, Google Translate wraps all URLs, including external ones, with https://translate.google.com/website? etc. Even links to Google Maps get this suboptimal functionality.
I do not need/want any (especially external) links to be translated recursively. Almost all of the linked sites provide their own international versions just fine.
Is there any way to turn the URL translation off? Altogether or per link?

No, not in any reasonable way. You're redirected to a website belonging to Google where Google sets rules. And they don't have any parameter to prevent the conversion.
A workaround is to convert href params to e.g. onclick with JS redirecting to external URLs, but that doesn't really seem worth it, considering it has bunch of drawbacks like removing user ability to copy the URL or open it in new window. Or generally not working for rare users that have disabled JS. So I don't recommend it.
